# Run Python file from double-click shortcut with arguments

Tags: python, windows

On Windows, I want to make a desktop shortcut to a Python script which runs with arguments.  I've configured the default double-click behavior for `.py` files to open with Python 3.8, so it works fine without arguments.  But when I pass arguments using the Windows shortcut, they are not recognized in Python.  For example, this code:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
input()
```

I made a desktop shortcut with target: `C:\test.py "some text"`.  Running this only prints the name of the script.

Comment: In the "open with" dialog, don't browse to the executable for any association that needs to accept command line arguments. It does not create a ProgId with a template command that includes `%*` for command line arguments. You should select the installed "Python" app from the list, which uses the installed "Python.File" ProgId. If the launcher is installed, which it is by default, it will have the Python icon overlayed by a rocket/shuttle being launched. This ProgId uses the launcher to support script shebangs and also sets a shell drop handler to drag and drop files onto a script icon.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't sys.argv a list with ['Name', Argument1, Argument2]?
So you should try

```
print(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: That's not necessary, since lists can be printed as strings.

Answer (score -1):

I'm answering my own question with one method I found that works, but I don't really like it.  This way, it will break when you upgrade to a newer version of Python, and if I have many of these shortcuts I would have to edit all of them.  I would like to use the Windows built-in "double-click" feature to save the preferred default opener program.

Change the shortcut target = `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Python...\python3.8.exe test.py "some text"`
Change the shortcut "start in" to the folder containing the code.

Comment: That's not necessary. Just make sure that .py files get opened by python.exe in your python38 folder. Target example for the shortcut: `C:\tests\test_args.py "TEST bla"`. Output: `['C:\\Python38\\test_args.py', 'TEST bla']`

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. It works if I change the "open with" app to python.exe. Before I was using Python 3.8 which doesn't work. I'm not sure what the difference is.  Unfortunately imports don't work this way...